# Is rent owed when landing on a property because of a card rather than a dice roll?

Tags: monopoly

If I land on a property because of a card, do I have to pay rent for the property I landed on?

For example, if I landed on Community Chest and the card stated to go to a Railroad, do I then have to pay the fee for landing on that property if it's owned by another player?

Answer (score 19):

The property can be bought (or auctioned) if it's unowned, and rent is owed to its owner otherwise.

---

The card in your example doesn't exist as a [Community Chest](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Community_Chest) card. There is such a [Chance](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Chance) card. It's exact text is

> Advance token to the nearest Railroad and pay owner twice the rental to which he/she is otherwise entitled.
>
> If Railroad is unowned, you may buy it from the Bank.

So, for that card, not only do you have to pay the fee, it's twice what it normally is!

---

Now, there are a number of other Chance cards that don't explicitly state that rent is entitled.

For example,

> Advance to Illinois Ave
>
> If you pass Go, collect $200

But as you may have noted, the first card quoted above said the rental fee was twice that "otherwise entitled". That means the owner of the space to which the Chance card moves you is normally entitled to rent.

Landing on a space because of a Chance card moved you there is no different than landing on a space as a result of rolling the dice. Rent is owed if the property is owned, or the property can be bought (or auctioned) if it's not.